# Discord User's ID with OAuth2

Tags: python-3.x, flask, oauth-2.0, discord

I'm trying to set up Discord OAuth authorization in my application.

The script generates a URL with authorization and then a redirects to a web page that should extract the `access _token` parameter from the URL and send it back to the server.

Help me set up fetching and sending response to my other server please .

```
from flask import Flask, request

application = Flask(__name__)

@application.route('/redirect')
def redirect_handler():
    access_token = request.args.get('access_token')
    if access_token:
        return access_token
    else:
        return "Error."

if __name__ == "__main__":
   application.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```

I expected that the script would be able to extract the "access_token" from the URL, but this did not happen. The URL looks like this;

```
https://tatarchik.cfd/login#token_type=Bearer&access_token=UXWVLCyTTL7tBDVRwzjcGA5qSC1zRs&expires_in=604800&scope=identify
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you didnt provide much code to work with, i'll suggest you can use the code example provided by [Discord](https://github.com/discord/discord-oauth2-example/blob/master/app.py). On the `callback` function after a user authorizes the application, you will get their `access_token` with `token['access_token']`. Make sure to change `OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID`, `OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET` and the `OAUTH2_REDIRECT_URI` variables.

```py
import os
from flask import Flask, session, redirect, request
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth2Session
import requests


OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID = 888888888888
OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET = ""
OAUTH2_REDIRECT_URI = 'http://localhost:5000/callback'

API_BASE_URL = os.environ.get('API_BASE_URL', 'https://discordapp.com/api')
AUTHORIZATION_BASE_URL = API_BASE_URL + '/oauth2/authorize'
TOKEN_URL = API_BASE_URL + '/oauth2/token'

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug = True
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET

if 'http://' in OAUTH2_REDIRECT_URI:
    os.environ['OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT'] = '1'

def token_updater(token):
    session['oauth2_token'] = token


def make_session(token=None, state=None, scope=None):
    return OAuth2Session(
        client_id=OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID,
        token=token,
        state=state,
        scope=scope,
        redirect_uri=OAUTH2_REDIRECT_URI,
        auto_refresh_kwargs={
            'client_id': OAUTH2_CLIENT_ID,
            'client_secret': OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET,
        },
        auto_refresh_url=TOKEN_URL,
        token_updater=token_updater)


@app.route('/')
def index():
    scope = request.args.get(
        'scope',
        'identify')
    discord = make_session(scope=scope.split(' '))
    authorization_url, state = discord.authorization_url(AUTHORIZATION_BASE_URL)
    session['oauth2_state'] = state
    return redirect(authorization_url)


@app.route('/callback')
def callback():
    if request.values.get('error'):
        return request.values['error']
    discord = make_session(state=session.get('oauth2_state'))
    token = discord.fetch_token(
        TOKEN_URL,
        client_secret=OAUTH2_CLIENT_SECRET,
        authorization_response=request.url)
    session['oauth2_token'] = token
    return token['access_token']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000, debug=False, use_reloader=False)
```